# "spacer" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I recently have had a huge big discussion about the word "spacer".

Between friends (all non-native English speakers) we had this big discussion that if the word "spacer" officially exists in English language with the meaning of "astronaut".

Can any language or literature professional or some native speakers comment if this word officially exists?

Comment: There is no such thing as "*officially exists in English language*".

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing "spacer" used in that sense, at least not in the past 30-40 years.  Perhaps in the 60s, when terminology was still being settled.

Comment: What @HotLicks said. But in the 60s a *spacer* might have applied to someone known to space out a lot. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Spaceman" is one of the definitions listed in the OED for this word, but it appears to only be used in Sci-Fi (which is why it cannot be found in most normal dictionaries).

One of the first usages was from the well-known author Isaac Asimov:

> I've read books about him. He was the greatest spacer there ever was.
>   <sub>1940 I. Asimov in *Astonishing Stories* Apr. 71/2</sub>

In addition, I found [this website](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/325) that lists dozens of examples of it being used with this meaning.

Comment: The fact that the word is used by some authors but has not been defined in Oxford or Merriam Webster dictionary, how might be explained?

Comment: @Morty that's what Laurel was explaining when he wrote "it appears to only be used in Sci-Fi."  It's a very rarely used term, apparently coined and only in use in a very narrow subculture, which is why most dictionaries don't define it.  But Oxford English Dictionary (OED) does define it because they have a very wide scope.

Comment: @Morty It doesn't see much, if any use outside of Sci-Fi. MW explains why some words are missing [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq-missing-words), and one of the reasons is if a word is "too specialized". The OED, on the other hand, is known for including many specialized and historical words.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Laurel 
I didn't find "spacer" as astronaut in OED though! 
Is it possible to answer this question: Does the word "spacer" exist (or it's just a word that a famous author has invented)?
I know my question looks strange, but I need an answer to that!

Comment: @Morty - Certainly the word "spacer" exists.  It's just that 99.9% of the uses are to refer to something that maintains a space between two other things.

Comment: @Morty You probably looked in [Oxford's free online dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/). By OED, I mean http//:www.oed.com, which is a different (premium) dictionary that also happens to be written by Oxford.

Comment: When you make a bead necklace, you may want to keep the beads apart from one another by alternating beads on a string with small cylinders, to save money by reducing the number of beads needed,  Since those little cylinders create extra space between the beads, they're called "spacers".  Or plumbing applications may require washers to be added to small pipes or screws to make extra space between parts that are threaded onto the pipes or screws.  If you can use "space" as a transitive verb in some context, then you can use the agentive -er suffix to form a corresponding agent noun "spacer".

Comment: Morty, it's possible that you have access to www.oed.com through your public or university library.